# TCSH alias for previous command string substitution

Tags: alias, tcsh

I would like to create an alias that substitutes all occurrences of an old string in the previous command with a new string in TCSH. I know I can do that with `!!:gas/old/new`, but I would like it in an alias so I can use `sub old new` format on the command line. I tried several different things with character escaping and could not get even a hardcoded sub to work (eg `alias sub \!\!:gas/old/new`) it just returns `Modifier failed.` and I cannot see how to use that to debug the issue. Should it be possible or is there a reason it cannot work? Is there an alternative tool that could do the same thing? It would be a bonus if I could use it on a previous command that wasn't the most recent.

```
•   :g: global (apply once for each ‘word’)
•   :a: all (apply as many times as possible for a ‘word’)
•   :s: substitute
```

Answer (score 0):

In an alias definition, `!` actually refers to arguments when the alias is called.  A colon modifier is used to pick out one or more of the arguments

```
> alias name_age "echo \!:1 is \!:2 years old"
> name_age Clark 80
   -->  Clark is 80 years old.
```

To access the *previous* command line, then modify the `!` to `!-1`.   `!-1:*` gives all the arguments, but not the command name itself.  `!-1:0*` will be the command plus all the arguments.

An alias to repeat the previous command:

```
> alias repeat "\!-1:0*"
> echo one two three
> repeat
   --> one two three
```

An alias to substitute a hardcoded word in the previous commmand:

```
> alias repeat_one_ten "\!-1:0*:s/one/ten/"
> echo one two three
> repeat_one_ten
   --> ten two three
```

Taking it one step further becomes a total mess though because you want to pass alias arguments into the modifier rules.

#### Solution !!   Use ^old^new !

tcsh already builds in a short cut to repeat the previous command, replacing 'old' with 'new'.

```
> echo one two three
> ^one^ten
--->  ten two three
```

Comment: great answer! ^one^ten will not let me search replace multiple instances like !!:gas/one/ten will though. Is there really no way to take your :s example one step further? I have several aliases that take command line args

Comment: I hadn't realized that ^old^new was limited to the first occurrence of 'old'.    I cannot say that there's no way to make an alias like you would like....but I think it's unlikely.